# azure devops cli to query worktiems

Tags: azure-devops, azure-cli

I want to use azure devops cli to query workitems using WIQL or saved query. I tried looking in azure cli documents [az boards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/boards/work-item?view=azure-cli-latest) but it has query by an workitem Id.
Can anyone please point me how to use az cli to query workitems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `az boards query` command with the `--wiql` parameter to query work items in Work Item Query Language format.

Here is an example:

```
az boards query --wiql "SELECT [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.AssignedTo], [System.State], [System.AreaPath], [System.IterationPath], [System.Tags], [System.CommentCount] FROM workitems WHERE [System.TeamProject] = 'sandbox' AND [System.State] IN ('Active') ORDER BY [System.IterationPath]"
```

Similarly, for running a saved query from the command line, use `--id` to pass the ID of an existing query.

For example:

```
az boards query --id f28b2cd7-843d-4129-aht5-6dcf1e04f11b
```

Reference:

- [az boards query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/boards?view=azure-cli-latest#az_boards_query)
- [Run a query from the command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/view-run-query?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#run-a-query-from-the-command-line)